# How can you add groups to a buefy b-taginput?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, buefy

I'm quite new to Buefy, vue, and javascript in general and I am trying to add a grouped drop down to a `b-taginput`

Adding `autocomplete` appears to enable the dropdown, but it's missing groups. Below is what I've got so far..

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.css">
</head>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/buefy/dist/buefy.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-field label="Tag">
    <b-taginput v-model="selected" :data="myDataTags" autocomplete open-on-focus type="is-primary"></b-taginput>
  </b-field>
  <b-field label="Group">
    <b-select placeholder="Select a character">
      <optgroup v-for="(option, key) in myData" v-bind:label="key">
        <option v-for="opt in option">
          {{ opt }}
        </option>
      </optgroup>
    </b-select>
  </b-field>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selected: [],
    myData: {
      'First': ['One', 'Two'],
      'Second': ['Three']
    }  
  },
  computed: {
    myDataTags() {
      var items = [];
      for (var key in this.myData) {
       if (this.myData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          var obj = this.myData[key];
          for (var prop in obj) {
                items.push(obj[prop]);            
          }
       }
    }
    return items;
    }
  }
})
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Konnor5092/z8doLt4j/124/

I've added a `b-select` which is how I would like my `b-taginput` dropdown to be displayed.

What can I do to achieve this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot do that directly because there is no slot to the entire dropdown, only for header, footer and individual items with `<template slot-scope="props">`.

In fact `b-taginput` is a combination of `b-autocomplete` component and a `v-for` of `b-tag` components. So you can use all `slots` of the [autocomplete component](https://buefy.org/documentation/autocomplete) (empty, header, footer) and `slots` of the [taginput component](https://buefy.org/documentation/taginput) (empty, header).

So, to do what you want, the only way is to fork the `b-taginput` component and customize the dropdown. Here is the code of this component: https://github.com/buefy/buefy/blob/dev/src/components/taginput/Taginput.vue

Answer (score 0):

Great news! Since v0.9.2 Buefy's Autocomplete and Taginput components have built-in support for grouped search results.

[Beufy documentation](https://buefy.org/documentation/autocomplete/#groups)

This should work:

```
<b-field label="Tag">
    <b-taginput 
        v-model="selected"
        :data="myData"
        autocomplete 
        open-on-focus
        type="is-primary"
        group-field="name"
        group-options="items"
    />
</b-field>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    selected: [],
    myData: [
      {
         name: 'First',
         items: ['One', 'Two'],
      },
      {
         name: 'Second',
         items: ['Three'],
      },
    ]
  },
})
```

It even works with options that are objects - the "field" prop on the taginput indicates what path to use for the options' labels in that case